# Which is the better way to create instance of PageObject?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, cucumber-jvm, pageobjects

I would like to know from the below which is better option for creating the instance of the *PageObject* class(Ex: LoginPage):-

1) Create an instance of Pageobject class in all the tests and steps (Wherever required)?

```
LoginPage loginpage = PageFactory.initElements(webDriver, LoginPage.class);
```

(or)

2) Create a class with a static method to return the instance for the requested *PageObject* class. In this method, check if the instance is null before creating a new instance for the requested class?

```
LoginPage loginpage = PageUtil.getPageObject("login");
```

Please advise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are multiple ways to do it. I like to create a `BaseClass()` and instantiate the `PageFactory.initElements(driver, this);` there. See my [gist](https://gist.github.com/safrrhmn/519dddc33fbf0bb0d78a). Also, the public repository [here](https://github.com/safrrhmn/SeleniumTestNG)

```
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.PageFactory;

/**
* Created by Saifur on 2/14/2015.
*/
public class BaseClass {

//global driver instance.
WebDriver driver;

//super constructor
public BaseClass(WebDriver _driver)
 {
   //assigning driver instance globally.
   driver = _driver;

   /*Instantiating all elements since this is super class
   and inherited by each and every page object */

   PageFactory.initElements(driver, this);
 }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Does creating multiple classes for the same PageObject class in the same test will have any performance impact?

Comment: @user3188928 Not that I know of. But, lot of people tends to create one single class for a single page that way maintainability is easier. But you can certainly have more than one. Please accept the answer if this is what have been looking for

Comment: sorry I typed wrong. I mean creating multiple classes for the same PageObject class in the same test?

Comment: Not really. You need to instantiate multiple classes in one test for the needs of tests anyway

Comment: Yes. But is it ok to instantiate same class multiple times? I'm using cucumber-webdriver-junit for automation. For most of the scenarios, step implementation are in different files and some steps need access to the same PageObject class. Is there a way to use same instance of the PageOBject class apart from the option (2) I mentioned in my question?

Comment: Can you show me some example of what you are exactly saying? Something like screenshots or screencast?

Comment: I have now modified page classes as per your suggeston as well as using DI container(pico container) for creating instances of page object class.  I'm not able to paste all the code for the example scenario here. I will include the screencast link in the evening.

Comment: yes. working as expected. Here is the screencast link [ http://www.screencast.com/users/jukumar/folders/Default/media/16ffd8e4-de5c-412d-a215-5354a0c08e92 ]. please let me know if anything can be improved.